# Dota 2 lagging in Steam when running on MacBook Pro

Tags: intel-graphics, steam, mac, macbook

I installed Ubuntu on my Macbook Pro recently. But DOTA 2 is very much laggy in **Ubuntu 16.04**. It runs crispy in OSX. I tried updating machine and all, but no use.

The graphics card shows **Intel Haswell Mobile** in Ubuntu and **Intel Iris Pro 1536 MB** in OSX. Is it a graphics related problem? How can this be fixed.

Note: I have seen Dota 2 running fine on Ubuntu with laptops of very ordinary specs.

Some more information as per comments:

1. The output of `lspci | grep VGA` is

   00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Crystal Well Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 08)
2. It plays 60 fps 4k videos perfectly fine.

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: Also, can you play a 1080p 60FPS video (such as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ) off of YouTube fine? Make sure to select the 60fps mode in the youtube menu.

Comment: [Edit] your question with the output of `lspci | grep VGA`

Comment: I have updated with the required information. I also tried to install AMD Graphics driver, which did not help.  So uninstalled it back.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem, and I managed to solve it on Arch linux. The problem was that OpenCL drivers were not installed. I guess the basic steps are same, so here they are:

1. Run `$ neofetch` command to check what Graphics card you are using.
   //Mine was Intel Crystal well.
2. Go to intel site and find what is the
   microarchitectre of your chip. For e.g. mine was Haswell as seen on
   https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/intel/crystal_well. My processor is
   also listed i7-4770HQ.
3. Install the relevant driver, as from this
   page - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GPGPU. Mine was
   `intel-opencl`.  Restart your computer.
4. Run `$ clinfo` . You should see a platform registered. OpenCL is enabled now.